# Redirect CPT to child?

Tags: wp-redirect

I have a CPT for which I want to redirect one parent to a specific child.

Example: /cpt_postname/ should redirect to /cpt_postname/a_different_cpt_postname/.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this with .htacess or wp_redirect (various errors).

After further thought, I think a solution is adding this to functions.php:

```
function custom_redirect() {
if (is_single('5627')) {
wp_redirect('http://----------.com');
exit;
}}
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_redirect');
```

Although I think that sorts my original question, I have a further problem, because I'm using a plugin to load pages by ajax - and the function isn't being applied... the page loads as normal, and only on refresh is the redirect triggered.

I realise this is likely beyond the permitted scope of questions here, but I'm including it for completeness.

Comment: Is `/cpt_postname/ ` the post type archive page? If you're redirecting to the same site you should be using `get_permalink()`.

Comment: The redirect has to happen within the javascript that loads the page, I'm not sure how you would achieve that without replacing the plugin's javascript code.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee ... Thanks. The cpt has no archive. The reason for wanting the redirect is that in this instance 'cpt_postname' is for a week schedule, and 'a_different_cpt_postname' is one of seven for individual days. 'cpt_postname' displays the content for monday with links to tue-sun. (An alternative would have been to simply use 'cpt_postname' and ajax-load individual days - but the page content would then be slower to load and harder to edit.) With hindsight, it may be better to avoid a redirect and thus not confuse users.

Comment: @ Milo ... Thanks. Yes, that's my problem - but I respect that plugin questions aren't welcome here and hence won't dwell... beyond hoping that there's some perhaps-obscure function which'll over-ride.